# multiple components in angular 8 feature module routing

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing

I have a main module and a feature module with multiple components. Below is the configuration for multiple routes in the feature routing file.

```
const priorityRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: 'abc', component: ComponentOne,runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
        { path: 'def', component: ComponentTwo,runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' }
]
```

and the main module routing is configured as:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:  'main',
    loadChildren: ()=>import('./main.module').then(m=>m.MainModule)
  }]
```

I am accessing them using

```
/main/abc
```

but navigation does not work. no error shows and component does not display.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to import and export `RouterModule` in `MainModule`?

```
@NgModule({
    ...,
  imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forChild(priorityRoutes),
    ...
  ], 
  exports: [
    ...
    RouterModule,
    ...
  ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did export RouterModule in main module routing but did not export in the feature module routing. That should be okay, right?